# Difference between finite and infinitesimal motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

I am studying Arnold Sommerfeld mechanics. Here they talk about finite and infinitesimal motion.

Quoted from the text:

> The simplest example of a non-holonomic condition is furnished by a sharp edged wheel rolling on a horizontal plane set. Such a wheel is restricted to move always in the direction it may have at any given instant never the less it is able to reach all points of its supporting plane even if at times only by pivoting about its sharp point of contact. **It therefore possesses more degrees of freedom in finite than infinitesimal motion**.
>   **In general, if a system subject to $r$ non- holonomic constraints has $f$ degrees of freedom in finite motion, it was only $(f-r)$ degrees of freedom in infinitesimal motion**.

Could someone help me understand this concept?

Comment: Infinitesimally, you can only drive your car back and forth, but given enough room (and gas), you can approach any point from any direction.

Comment: I think i sort of get it, in an infinitesimal motion you can either pivot the wheel about the point of contact or rotate the wheel but not both at the same time